# SSRS Chart with Grouping like in Excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I wasnt able to find anything like this yet... but here is what i need to do:

I have a query result like this:

ID Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 ... Data7

1   12    13    15     1   ...  12
2   12    13    15     1   ...  12 
3   12    13    15     1   ...  12 
4   12    13    15     1   ...  12

I need to make a BarChart With 2 Values, 1 is the first row (ID=1) one is the last row (ID=4). The column headers DataX is what i need the series to be paired by.

Example: 
ID Insured Uninsured Rejected
1 12 3 0
4 16 9 2

In the BarChart i need to see the number of insured or ID=1 and ID=2 next to each other, the number of Uninsured and rejected the same.

I feel like i have tried all ways possible but was not able to get anything besides a BarChart where all values of ID=1 where displayed and then all values for ID=2 where displayed next to each other.

Im sure this was a very confusing way to describe it, but i hope someone can understand what i am looking for.

NOTE: I tried to do this in Excel, and it worked within 2 minutes. I set the filter: Series on the 2 rows that i wanted, and set the Categories to the dataX Columns as described, and everything looked great. When i tried to translate this into SSRS i was able to do all the same things in the Series and Categories, but then i had to put in values and that screwed everything up.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Can you create a dataset that pulls data and assign it to a chart components first, please? That would give a better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you need to add a grouping to your values by a spanning factor.

[image]